# How do I convert a collection of canvases into an animated gif in WinRT?

Tags: c#, javascript, windows, windows-runtime, gif

I have a javascript Windows 8 application, and I need to convert a bunch of canvases into an animated gif. Here's what I have so far:

I can convert one canvas to a base64 encoded png like this (in javascript):

`var base64png = myCanvas.toDataURL()`

I can then convert this encoded image into an array of bytes (in a c# class library):

```
private byte[] GetBytesFromBase64(string base64)
{
    string data = base64.Split(',')[1]; // get everything after comma
    return Convert.FromBase64String(data);
}
```

I can then use these bytes to create a gif, and save it on the disk (again, in the c# class library):

```
public async void ConvertToGif(string image)
    {
        // Note: The following line includes methods not shown in the question, but they work
        IRandomAccessStream stream = await ConvertToRandomAccessStream(
                                           ConvertToMemoryStream(
                                           GetBytesFromBase64(image)));

        var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
        var pixels = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();

        var file = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("test.gif", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        var outStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.GifEncoderId, outStream);

        encoder.SetPixelData(
            decoder.BitmapPixelFormat, 
            BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
            decoder.PixelWidth, 
            decoder.PixelHeight,
            decoder.DpiX, 
            decoder.DpiY,
            ReplaceTransparentWithWhite(pixels));


        await encoder.FlushAsync();
        outStream.Dispose();
    }
```

This, however, only saves one canvas as one gif. How do I add frames to the gif? There is a `GifEncoder` class in the `System.Media.Imaging` namespace, but it seems to not be included in the WinRT .Net framework. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you build it your self as you've already got code to convert a Canvas to a single GIF file. Basically, an animated GIF is just a series of GIF files within a container GIF file. While the specification is a bit wordy, you should find [this example](http://rick.bloggingabout.net/2005/05/10/howto-create-an-animated-gif-using-net-c/) from the .NET 1.1 days very useful.

Although the standard file format didn't directly allow animation, through "extensions" animations are allowed. The details are well documented on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format#Animated_GIF) Wikipedia page.

The core of what you'll need to do is write out a custom header block for the file, and then the individual streams for each animated GIF frame.